# how to traverse path and find files and directories using python?

Tags: python, file, os.walk

i have a python code that traverse a given path and list all files and directories  but the problem is that when a file exist inside a subdirectory  the system crash and display **FileNotFoundError**   that the file does not  exist in the given path and its right because it display the **path/file**  and not the **path /folder/file**

how can i fix this error?

code:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(src):

        print(f'Found directory: {dirpath}')
        # for file_name in files:
        if len(dirnames)==0 and len(files)==0:
                print("this directory is empty")
        else:
            print(files)

        for name in files:
            full_file_name = os.path.join(src, name)
            print("files: ",full_file_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`full_file_name = os.path.join(src, name)` should be `full_file_name = os.path.join(dirpath, name)`